# FileSystemWatcher not firing .Created on FileInfo.Create( )

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm attempting to use the `FileSystemWatcher` object to watch directories for when new files are created to maintain a combo-box of files present in real time.

Unfortunately, files created in code are not firing the event handler attached to the `Created` event.

Why is this not working, and what can I do to make it work, using the `FileSystemWatcher` object? ( I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446167/filesystemwatcher-not-firing-events-when-file-written-using-fprintf-or-printf) and would rather not have to depend on an external library to make this work ).

I have seen the `FileSystemWatcher` work when I right-click -> create new file, but I need it to work when the program calls `.Create( )` on a `FileInfo` object.

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace MCVEConsole {
    class Program {
        [PermissionSet( SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust" )]
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(
                Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments )
                ).CreateSubdirectory( "MCVEConsole" );
            FileSystemWatcher fSW = 
                new FileSystemWatcher( myDirectory.FullName, "*.txt" ) {
                    NotifyFilter = 
                        NotifyFilters.CreationTime | 
                        NotifyFilters.LastAccess | 
                        NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                };

            fSW.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler( _Changed );
            fSW.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler( _Changed );
            fSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            new FileInfo(
                Path.Combine( myDirectory.FullName, "foo.txt" ) ).Create( ).Close( );

            void _Changed( object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e ) =>
                Console.WriteLine( "bar" );

            Console.WriteLine( "Press any key to continue..." );
            Console.ReadKey( );
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for the `[PermissionSet]` attribute is because I noticed it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx), and thought that it may be the problem ( It was not ).

Comment: Note that Create returns an opened stream that is not sharable. Try closing the stream.

Comment: @mikez See edit. Added your suggestion. Nothing changed.

Comment: @HansPassant Godsend. Would you care to phrase your comment in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NotifyFilters.FileName`. That's what I've had to add to see new files being created. Not what I expected but gave the result I needed.